# follows by - follows from

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Assume that "**P**" and "**Q**" are logic propositions. I want to say "Since **Q** is true, so **P** is true". I want to say this, like one of the two sentences below. Which one is true (better)?

- **P** follows by **Q**.
- **P** follows from **Q**.

Thank you.

Comment: You can also say **Q implies P** (Q => P). http://www.math.niu.edu/~richard/Math101/implies.pdf

Comment: @MorganFR Note, however, that *imply* is ambiguous: it may designate either *entailment* (a necessary inference) or *implicature* (a default but 'cancellable' inference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

B follows from A

means that B can be derived logically from A.

"Follows *from*" is idiomatic.